# Cross-browser working of jQuery client-side uploading script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following script for uploading an image and placing it in a `<asp:Image>` control.

```
function ShowUploadDialog(img) {
    var input = $('form input[type=file]');
    var image = $('#' + img);
    input.on('change', function () {
        var file = document.getElementById(input.attr('id')).files[0];
        if (file) {
            if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    image.attr('src', e.target.result);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }
    });
    $('form input[type=file]').click();
}
```

But it works fine **only** for IE. In other browsers it doesn't work. Why?

Or maybe there is another way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Does `cross-browser` mean support for `lynx` (`sudo apt-get install lynx`), too? :-)

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you, but from text of my question it's clear that I need working of my script in several browsers :) The main priority is FireFox.

Comment: I was joking, `lynx` is [a command line web browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29). :-) It's great!

Comment: Sorry, I hear about it the first time :)

Comment: Maybe because an input doesn't have a `files` attribute?

Comment: It only has an `accept` attribute. And even IE does not support the `files` property, only new versions do.

Comment: @Poetro, but how can I implement this functionality for IE, FF and Safari? Can you help me?

Comment: @MaxZhukov you should use the `accept` attribute of the field, and use [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/), although that is not widely supported.